# How can I keep generated random number once a new one in an array is generated?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am generating an objects in array every time the user creates one new in front end.
I wan't to display them randomly in screen. I generate the random position for them but when I create a new object, all the previous objects get the new random number.

So here are the elements, which get rendered on screen.
Everytime when user click button "add new", the new object is pushed to the data array.

```
  const randomNum = (min: number, max: number): number => {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (max - min + 1) + min);
  };

  const elements = data.map(() => {
    return (
      <Fade left>
        <div
          style={{
            position: 'absolute',
            top: `${randomNum(0, 51)}%`,
            right: `${randomNum(0, 51)}%`,
          }}
        >
          <Image
            alt="Smiley"
            src={smiley}
          />
        </div>
      </Fade>
    );
  });
```

create functions:

```
 function handleAddInput(id: number) {
    setData(
      update(data, {
        data: {
          $push: [
            {
              name: '',
              id,
            },
          ] as any,
        },
      })
    );
  }
```

and button add new html part:

```
           <div
              className="text-gray"
              onClick={() => handleAddInput(data.data.length + 1)}
            >
              Click to add
            </div>
            <div>
               {elements}
            </div>
```

**I think that I should use the useEffect hook, but I can't get it to work right.**

Thanks to everyone for help!